# Understanding Lock class vs synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

In Java Concurrency In Practice I came the technique to avoid deadlock. He proposed to acquire use `tryLock()` when we need to acquire multiple locks to ensure consistency. As follows:

```
public void m(MyObject o1, MyObject o2){
    synchronized(o1){
        synchornized(o2){
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Instead we'd better of using this:

```
public void m(MyObject o1, MyObject o2){
    while(true){
        if(o1.lock.tryLock(){
             try{
                 if(o2.lock.tryLock(){ 
                     try{
                          //...
                     } finally {
                          o2.lock.unlock();
                     }
                 }
            } finally { 
                  o2.lock.unlock()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now he goes:

> This technique works only when the two locks are acquired together; if
>   multiple locks are acquired due to nesting of method calls you cannot
>   just realease the outer lock, even if you know you hold it.

It's not quite obvious. Why cannot we use this when calling a method within a method? Can you give an example?

Comment: Check out this comment made by @Boris the Spider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573218/why-timed-lock-technique-doesnt-work-if-multiple-locks-are-acquired-due-to-the

Answer (score 2):

I've just looked into the book and found that the quoted statement was made in the context of timed locks (using `tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit)`), but I think it also applies for your `tryLock()` example.

Theoretically you can still use this technique with nested method calls, but it gets unwieldy really fast. Let's consider a simple example where you try to obtain some lock in the method `foo(Lock lock)` and if you succeed, a couple of stack frames later you try to obtain another lock in the method `bar(Lock lock)`.

- If both of your methods use `while (true)` until they finally manage to obtain their lock, you can easily get into a deadlock if one thread has obtained `A` in `foo()`, another has obtained `B` in `foo()` and now both are spinning endlessly in `bar()`, trying to acquire each other's locks.
- If you loop only in the `foo()` method and return from `bar()` when the lock acquisition is unsuccessful, you may be able to avoid a deadlock, but now:

  - `foo()` and `bar()` are tightly coupled
  - depending on exactly how much later `bar()` is called, the vulnerability window between the acquisition of the first lock and the acquisition of the second lock can be very big
  - you need to recalculate the whole branch starting from the loop in `foo()`
  - the targeted codepath becomes really hard to follow and easy to break
- If you use timed locks, you'll still have some of the above problems, you'll need to handle `InterruptedException`, and you'll need to decide how you'd want to loop.

  - The general technique is already prone to generating a number of `IllegalMonitorStateException`s, which is not too nice

If you are regularly acquiring the same sub-set of locks and using the same sub-set of resources, you may want to consider lock coarsening (combining a couple of your locks in one) or redefining your resource protection policies so that you don't need to obtain multiple levels of locks a in a single workflow.

P.S. After a couple of attempts, I got both the `tryLock()` and the timed `tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit)` approaches to work with the above two-method, two-lock scheme. Not pretty, and I could easily see how a simple change in the protected section would break the whole scheme or make it just too complex.