# Why timed lock technique doesn't work if multiple locks are acquired due to the nesting of method calls

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

Quote from java concurrency in practice:

> Using timed lock acquisition to acquire multiple locks can be
>   effective against deadlock even when timed locking is not used
>   consistently throughout the program. If a lock acquisition times out,
>   you can release the locks, back off and wait for a while, and try
>   again, possibly clearing the deadlock condition and allowing the
>   program to recover. (**This technique works only when the two locks are
>   acquired together; if multiple locks are acquired due to the nesting
>   of method calls, you cannot just release the outer lock, even if you
>   know you hold it**.)

Can you clarify bolded text ?

Maybe it is my translation issue but I don't see explicit difference between 2 and 'multiple' locks and what the problem of nested method calls?

Comment: See: [the dining philosophers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem).

Comment: @Boris the Spider, this example provided in the begining of this chapter.

Comment: So if we have `eat(acquireRightFork(acquireLeftFork()))`, using timed locks won't help at all as if we back off `acquireRightFork`, we still hold the left fork lock so this does nothing. We need to try and acquire them together and back off **both** if we fail - whilst for this problem a trivial rearrangement of the order of operations will achieve that; this is not always possible.

Comment: But if inside the *acquireRightFork*: **if (inputBoolean){ rightFork.tryLock(){....}}**

Comment: @Boris the Spider The problem if we have for example 5 locks(>2) and we should to acquire 2 or more locks ?

Comment: @Boris the Spider in book provided example with transfer money from one account to another. Is it good usage of timed locking technique or not? Please, provide more detailed answer